# Coupled Kazdan-Warner type equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Famous work of Kazdan and Warner shows that given $u\geq 0$ and a constant $c>0,$ the following equation in $f$ has a unique solution:
\begin{align*}
\Delta f+ u e^f=c
\end{align*}
I am interested in a coupled version of this problem, we have $u_1, u_2\geq 0, c_1,c_2$ positive constants. Then I want to solve for $f_1$ and $f_2$:
\begin{align*}
&\Delta f_1+ u_1 e^{f_1+f_2}=c_1,\\
&\Delta f_2+ u_2 e^{f_1+f_2}=c_2
\end{align*}

Comment: Add equations, solve for $f_1+f_2$, subtract equations, solve for $f_1-f_2$?

Comment: @DeaneYang subtraction doesn't give $f_1-f_2$ in the exponential term.

Comment: Yes but the equation is now a linear PDE for the unknown function $f_1-f_2$.

Comment: I see, yeah. Missed that. Thanks!